# Postfix relay on multiple local smtp servers

Tags: smtp, postfix-mta

I have two SMTP servers listening on ports 2525 and 2526.
But I have  only 1 public IP address.
I'd like to use postfix (already installed on my server) to receive emails only for domain xxx.company.com and domain yyy.company.com, and redirect those emails to server 1 (port 2525) for domain xxx.company.com and server 2 (port 2526) for domain yyy.company.com.

Postfix will not be used to send emails. Just receive.

I tried several postfix configurations but I haven't figured out how to do this properly.
For now, I end up with this:
In main.cf:

```
mydomain = company.com
mydestination = xxx.company.com, yyy.company.com
relay_domains = xxx.company.com, yyy.company.com
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
local_recipient_maps =
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
```

In transport.cf:

```
*xxx.company.com 2525:[localhost]
*yyy.company.com 2526:[localhost]
```

In master.cf, the following line has been uncommented:

```
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
```

But I still have an "unknown user" error if my maillog file.
I would like to be more accurate for local_recipients so I don't let the entire world enter my postfix.

Does anyone have an out-of-the-box example of such kind of configuration ?

Thanks,
Jeremy B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `main.cf` should be

```
#/etc/postfix/main.cf
mydomain = company.com
mydestination = xxx.company.com, yyy.company.com
relay_domains = 
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
local_recipient_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/local_users
```

also add the following files

```
#/etc/postfix/local_users
# Here ACCEPT can be anything,postfix doesn't use it.
someuser@xxx.company.com ACCEPT
someuser@yyy.company.com ACCEPT

#/etc/postfix/transport
xxx.company.com   smtp:[localhost]:2525
yyy.company.com   smtp:[localhost]:2526
# modify localhost, if the server1 and server2 is not on localhost
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi Clement, thanks for the reply. I have updated the configuration as you said. I hadn't the local_users file, so I created it. Does it really not matter to put 'someuser' in this file. 'Cause I really don't know who can be the sender of the email (the email prefix is random). I'm just sure about the domains. However, trying this new configuration get me a `Recipient address rejected: User unknown in local recipient table`. Thanks for your time

Comment: OK, problem solved. Removing email prefix (before @) in /etc/postfix/local_users is allowed to act as a wildcard. And the classic 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost finished the job. Tnanks again Clement. It was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

1. Inside **/etc/postfix/main.cf**
   Make sure this line is there

   `transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport`
2. In **/etc/postfix/transport** add your logic

   `something@domain.local   smtp:[localhost]:2525`

   `anotherthing@domain.local  smtp:[localhost]:3535`
3. Make sure the permissions are correct

   `sudo chmod 644 /etc/postfix/transport`
4. Apply config changes

   `sudo postmap /etc/postfix/transport`
5. Reload **Postfix**

   `sudo postfix reload`